# DataType for Maths & Science Equations & Fomulas- SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.  I have a small project for educational department work.  For that I need to store maths & science equations and formulas.  This means the data may contain values with superscripts and subscripts.

I wish to save the data in same format.  Is there an appropriate data type that will suit my requirements?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `NVARCHAR` datatype if you want to store your formuale and equations as text. You will also need to concatenate the special symbols such as subscripts or indices to your string with the `NCHAR` function as shown [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2011/10/30/superscripts-subscripts-special-characters-and-unicode.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If this column is used exclusively to store Math equations + Science Formulae, I would go with an Xml Column, and then store the data in [MathML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML). Paragraphs of text, e.g. explanations, could use  `<mtext>` elements.